# Trigger Failing when calling Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am truly hoping someone can help me out...

I have a trigger to handle the insert of a new record to a table. This trigger, as you will see below, inserts a record into another table, which in turns executes a trigger on that table, that calls a stored procedure (I tried to do it within the trigger itself, but it failed and was difficult to test where it was failing, so I moved it into its own little unit.)

Within the stored procedure, there is a call to extract information from the Active Directory database (ADSI) and update the newly inserted record. However, this is where it fails when called by the trigger. When I call it by simply executing it, and passing along the record to be updated, it works great... Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please!!!

Trigger #1 in YYY

```
USE [YYY]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[NewCustodian]    Script Date: 08/04/2014 09:38:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NewCustodian]
ON [YYY].[dbo].[Custodians]
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CaseID varchar(20);
    DECLARE DBcursor CURSOR  FOR 
            SELECT [XXX].[dbo].[tblCase].CaseID from [XXX].[dbo].[tblCase] Where [XXX].[dbo].[tblCase].SQLSVR_Case_ID = 'YYY';
    Open DBcursor; FETCH DBCursor into @CaseID;
    CLOSE DBcursor; DEALLOCATE DBcursor;

    DECLARE @NAME varchar(255);
    DECLARE @TAG varchar(255);

    SELECT @NAME = name FROM inserted;
    SELECT @TAG = tag FROM inserted;

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select eID from [XXX].[dbo].[tblNames] 
                    WHERE eID = @TAG and CaseID = @CaseID)
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [XXX].[dbo].[tblNames] (CaseID, Name, eID) 
                Values (@CaseID, @NAME, @Tag);
        END
END
```

Trigger #2 in XXX

```
USE [XXX]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tblNames_New]    Script Date: 08/04/2014 08:56:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:       
-- Create date:  
-- Description:  
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tblNames_New]
ON [XXX].[dbo].[tblNames]
AFTER INSERT

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @NamesID varchar(10)
DECLARE @TAG varchar(10);
DECLARE @return_value int

SELECT @NamesID = namesID FROM inserted

EXEC dbo.UpdateNames @NamesID;
End
```

Stored procedure:

```
USE [XXX]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateNames]    Script Date: 08/04/2014 08:14:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:       
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateNames] 
    @NamesID int 
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @eID varchar(10);
    DECLARE @TAG varchar(10);
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(555);
    DECLARE @DBresults as table (
        eID nvarchar(100),
        mobile nvarchar(100),
        mail nvarchar(100),
        phone nvarchar(100),
        name nvarchar(50),
        legacyExchangeDN nvarchar(100),
        Title nvarchar(100),
        homeDirectory nvarchar(100));
    DECLARE @mobile nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @mail nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @phone nvarchar(100) = 'Error'
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @legacyExchangeDN nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @Title nvarchar(100) = 'Error'
    DECLARE @homeDirectory nvarchar(100)

    SET @eID = (Select eID from [XXX].[dbo].[tblNames] Where NamesID = @NamesID)

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM OpenQuery ( ADSI, ''SELECT homeDirectory,Title,legacyExchangeDN,displayName, telephoneNumber, mail, mobile,samAccountName
      FROM ''''LDAP://domain.com''''
      WHERE objectClass =  ''''User''''  and samAccountName = ''''' + @eID+ ''''''') As tblADSI'

    INSERT INTO @DBresults 
       EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    DECLARE DBcursor CURSOR  FOR 
        SELECT * from @DBresults;
    Open DBcursor; FETCH DBCursor into @eID, @mobile, @mail, @phone, @Name, @legacyExchangeDN, @Title, @homeDirectory;
    CLOSE DBcursor; DEALLOCATE DBcursor;

    UPDATE XXX.dbo.tblNames
        SET Job_Title = @Title,
            Phone = @Phone
         Where NamesID = @NamesID;
END
```

Comment: You're using a cursor to retrieve and store a single value into a variable in the first trigger?

Comment: A trigger, which contains a **cursor**, which then calls another trigger, which in turns calls a stored procedure that updates ADSI and again contains another cursor...... good heavens! A **trigger** should be very small, fast, nimble. Do **NOT** do any extensive processing in a trigger! ***NEVER*** If you need processing - make the trigger insert a row into a "command" table, and then have a separate, async process that does the heavy lifting! And also: **inside a trigger**, ***N E V E R . . . E V E R*** use a cursor!

Comment: WOW this is mess. You have a cursor inside a trigger. The cursor does not query INSERTED. It can only handle a single row insert. The performance issues from using a cursor inside a trigger are staggering. Why in the world are you using a cursor to populate a single value? Your second trigger has the same basic flaw, it cannot handle set based operations. Then your stored proc is using the same flawed concept of using a cursor to populate a variable.

Comment: Ok Guys.. Instead of criticizing everything I did wrong, How do I do it correctly... Please note, until last week, I had NEVER written a trigger... Didn't know they even existed. I do not proclaim to know ANYTHING About them. I understand the need to criticize, but come on, help me out.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment - a trigger should be *extremely small, nimble, lean* - do not do any extensive and time-consuming processing inside a trigger, and avoid anything that would cause performance bottlenecks, especially cursors!

The reason for this is the fact that a trigger will be triggered whenever an `INSERT` operation happens, you have no control over when and how many times it gets called. The main app will *wait and hang* while the trigger is at work - so therefore, don't make this a long time - return very quickly from your trigger to go on with your main app.

My approach would be:

- create a new separate table where you insert some key pieces of information into from your first original trigger

  ```
  CREATE TABLE NewCustodianInserted 
  (
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
      CaseID VARCHAR(20), 
      Tag VARCHAR(255),
      Handled BIT DEFAULT (0)
  );
  ```
- change your original trigger on the `Custodians` table to just insert those key pieces of information into your new "command" table:

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NewCustodian]
  ON [YYY].[dbo].[Custodians]
  AFTER INSERT
  AS BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     -- insert key pieces about the new custodian into "command" table
     INSERT INTO dbo.NewCustodianInserted (CaseID, Tag)
        SELECT i.CaseId, i.Tag
        FROM Inserted i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [XXX].[dbo].[tblNames] WHERE eID = i.Tag AND CaseID = i.CaseID)
  END
  ```
- in a separate process, e.g. a SQL Server Agent job that is scheduled to run every 5 mînutes (or whatever makes sense for your application), read the "command" table, get the new custodians to handle, call that long-running stored procedure updating Active Directory from it. Here, since this runs asynchronously from your main application, it's ok to use a cursor which you almost have to since you want to call a stored procedure for every row in your new table.

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE HandleNewCustodians
  AS 
  BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     DECLARE @CaseID VARCHAR(20);
     DECLARE @Tag VARCHAR(255);
     DECLARE @NamesID varchar(10);

     DECLARE CustodianCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
     FOR 
        SELECT CaseID, Tag FROM dbo.NewCustodianInserted WHERE Handled = 0

     OPEN CustodianCursor

     FETCH NEXT FROM CustodianCursor INTO @CaseID, @Tag;

     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
         SELECT @NamesID = NameID 
         FROM [XXX].[dbo].[tblNames] WHERE eID = @Tag AND CaseID = @CaseID

         EXEC dbo.UpdateNames @NamesID;

         FETCH NEXT FROM CustodianCursor INTO @CaseID, @Tag;
     END

     CLOSE CustodianCursor;
     DEALLOCATE CustodianCursor;
   END
  ```

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for when I requested help!